# jQuery position altering for sticky headers

Tags: jquery, scroll, position, absolute

The following is a little script that simulates the sticky header effect seen on iOS devices.

```
$('.scrolllist').scroll(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').each(function(){
            if($(this).position().top <= 0){
                $(this).addClass('abs').find('strong').removeClass('mov');

                if($(this).position().top <= ($(this).height() * -1)){
                    $(this).removeClass('abs');
                    $(this).find('strong').addClass('mov');            
                }
                else {
                    $(this).addClass('abs');
                    $(this).find('strong').removeClass('mov');   
                }
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('abs').find('strong').removeClass('mov');
            }
        });
    });
```

It changes the position of each  element by changing its status from `postion:absolute, top:0` to `position:absolute, bottom:0;` whilst also changing the containing `<ul>` from `position:relative` to `position:static`

SAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/dMJqj/80/

Is there anything that can be done to smoothen it up a bit. It looks a bit jerky on Chrome and Firefox and sometimes it can take a fraction of a second to trigger which is noticeable because the sticky header  appears to flash.

Comment: Looks quite smooth for me in FF and Chrome. I would be more annoyed by the `strongs` overlapping the scrollbar.

Comment: A potential issue here, is that your code is invalid. A `ul` can only have `li`elements as its direct children. So you would need to either wrap your `strong` tags in an `li` or you would need to move them outside of the `ul`.

Comment: @Christoph That is also annoying. Do you know how to stop it from doing that.

Comment: As Christoph already mentioned, your HTML is not valid. You can easily avoid that buy using normal `<li>`Elements and using a `:first-child` selector. Also, look a the following article by John Resig, in which he explains how to deal with scroll events: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine that the twitching you're seeing is a result of performance issues within jQuery and JavaScript

These articles are rich with some tips on optimizing the performance of your scripts:

- [Your
  jQuery: Now With 67% Less Suck](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck)
- [5 Performance Tuning Tricks for jQuery](http://jonraasch.com/blog/5-performance-tuning-tricks-for-jquery)

Also -- more than that, it looks like the `abs` class is getting repeatedly added and remove at every firing of the `scroll` event when a list's `position.top < 0`

By itself that doesn't cause visual twitching but it does cause a small bit of memory to be burned unnecessarily.

Also as a few mentioned up above, your HTML was not valid.

See this fiddle with a few optimization techniques applied, valid HTML and removal of some unnecessary class manipulation:

http://jsfiddle.net/DW4pP/

Comment: I'm just +1ing this because I wrote one of the articles you linked and I'm an egotistical jerk. ;)

Comment: I never saw this answer at the time but thank you for it. I long since moved beyond jQuery for performance reasons but the fundamentals I have learnt over the years are about not using selectors on performance intensive triggers. I find that everything that needs to change should be held in variables on DOM load and all calculations of when and how it changes calculated to. The scroll event then simply triggers changes when those calculations are applicable. If the screen size changes or the DOM is injected with new content, the setup calculations are performed again.